# Lindblad equation solution

Tags: density-operator, time-evolution, open-quantum-systems

I have been trying to solve a Lindblad Equation and then thought about whether there is a closed form Lindblad Equation solution for most types. Googling hasn't lead me to anything useful. So, is there some sort of generalized Lindblad Equation solution?

I am looking for something like the Schrondinger solution 
$U = \exp(-i H t / \hbar)$, but for Lindblad.

Comment: The Lindblad equation is more or less as complicated as the Schrodinger equation. Is there a general solution to the Schrodinger equation?

Comment: @DanielSank Yes there is a general solution to the Schrödinger equation; and also to the Lindblad equation, even if they are a little bit different.

Comment: @yuggib well, if you mean a general solution in terms of eigenstates, then yes, I agree. It's really not clear to me what TanMath wants. I hope he/she will edit the question to make it more specific and clear.

Comment: @DanielSank For the Schrödinger equation, I mean a general solution as an evolution equation on Hilbert spaces; for the Lindblad equation as a semigroup equation on Banach spaces. I will make an answer to clarify.

Comment: @yuggib Oh you just mean $\exp[-i t H / \hbar]$?

Comment: @DanielSank Yes, of course ;-)

Comment: Check out the Kraus operators, any kind of quantum events (not restricting to Lindbladian evolution) can be represented in a Kraus sum. If you have the initial density matrix then in principle you can determine what is it at any time; easier in Markovian case. There are some procedures to get the Kraus operators from a Lindblad equation

Answer (score 4):

The analogy is based on writing the Lindblad equation in a Liouville form $\dot{\rho} = \cal{L} \rho$ with the Liouville *superoperator*
$\cal{L}$ being the generator of the (semigroup) evolution for the density matrix $\rho$.
The solution is then formally $\rho(t) = e^{\cal{L} t} \rho(0)$.

Comment: What do you mean by $e^{\cal{L}t}\rho(0)$? In the expansion of the exponential, 
 $\sum_n \frac{(t\cal{L}[\rho(0)])^n}{n!}$, what does $(\cal{L}[\rho(0)])^n$ mean? do you apply $\cal{L}$ succesivelly on $\rho(0)$?

Comment: Yes, I apply $\cal{L}$ succesivelly on $\rho(0)$. Note that the superoperator $\cal{L}$ acts on $\rho(0)$ from right and left!

Answer (score 1):

We always solve the Lindblad form linear differential equations by numerical methods, such as fourth order Runge-Kutta method. If you want the steady state solution in analytic method, you can read this paper: PHYSICAL REVIEW A 92, 022116 (2015). I don't know if I solved your question.